# Angular 2: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

**Short story:**, I am getting an error `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'xx'. Current value: 'xx'.` when I update a variable from my component.

**Long story:**
I have a `ParentComponent` that contains the variable I am updating named `totalAmount`. Then I have a `ChildComponent` which affects the value of `totalAmount` but doesn't have access to the said variable. What happens is I have a `subtotal` variable in my `ParentComponent` which I pass to `ChildComponent` using `@Input` then I just recalculate the `totalAmount` from the `ParentComponent` since I have access to `subtotal` in it. Just like this:

`ParentComponent.ts`

```
this.totalAmount = this.subtotal + (some other values)
```

Then I display it on my `ParentComponentTemplate.html` like this:

```
<span>{{ totalAmount | money }}</span>
```

**And it all works fine**. Then suddenly the `totalAmount` had to be in an `input` box because there should be a way that it can be overriden. So instead of a `span` element I had to do it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="totalAmount" [(ngModel)]="totalAmount" />
```

Now that's when the problem starts. Everytime the `subtotal` in my `ChildComponent` changes, I get the error `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'xx'. Current value: 'xx'`.

Now I've read several articles about this already that it is a feature in Angular but how do we go about this? Is there a solution to this instead of a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the child component?

Comment: Could you provide the two classes / components? You would need to refactor your code into a unidirectional dataflow. The flow would be correct with an EventEmitter or a service, where you subscribe to the change and then you will update the value, instead updating the value directly.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="totalAmount" [(ngModel)]="amountDue" />` i hope this is typo you should bind textbox with `totalAmount `...

Comment: added my answer can help you out

Answer (score 2):

The solution is that you must understand the error and change your code accordingly.

Although pretty explicit, this error doesn't state that it is a *lifecycle error*.

If you want to resolve that, you will need to follow the lifecycle, instead of trying and see what happens.

And although you seem to believe you posted enough code, you didn't : next time post your whole code instead of an explanation, because even though it seems clear to you, it isn't for me.

Finally, javascript variables are passed by reference : this means that when you change the value of an input, you change the reference, not the value.

So, what you could try :

- the parent has the total amount
- the child doesn't have any `@Input`
- when the value of the `<input>` changes in the child, you emit an event
- the parent listens to that event, and changes the total value accordingly

Comment: How do you do the fourth step?

Comment: `<child-component (onValueChanged)="updateTotalAmount($event)"></child-component>` speaks to you ? (honest quesiton, no sarcasm)

Comment: What is `$event` there? the subtotal or total?

Comment: Given my answer, it would be the subtotal that will be added to the total.

Comment: Thanks for answering even though I didn't post any code.

Answer (score 2):

Now that's when the problem starts. Everytime the subtotal in my ChildComponent changes, I get the error Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'xx'. Current value: 'xx'.

---

Error is coming when you are chaning subtotal in your child component.

And you are using subtotal in you parent component here

```
ParentComponent.ts

this.totalAmount = this.subtotal + (some other values)
```

that is causing problem.

---

**Solution** might help you is do code like this

---

in childcomponent.ts

```
Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this.parent.subtotal = calculatesubtotal );
```

Have look : [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: @trichetriche- thats not work around , thats ligeal solution but however if i can get more code that can help to figure out better solution, based on given details i have given my answer ... but agree with you that this last solution one can try out after looking at code

Comment: I would suggest handling the lifecycle and component interactions better, before using a promise. This would be the "native" way of handling this error, that's why using a promise is a workaround (for me at least)